# sampling distribution of p̂ problem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

**Rh-positive blood factor is found in approximately 85% of North Americans.

(a) Rh-positive blood factor is found in approximately 85% of North Americans.**

I figured this of a sampling distribution of p̂

so normalcdf(x, e99, u, σ) = normalcdf(5, e99, 0.85, sqrt(0.85(1-0.85)/7))

but I'm not getting the answer  0.9262

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: title has repeated problem statement

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.